# Using (1:n) with inherited classes works weirdly in gfortran

Tags: inheritance, fortran, gfortran, fortran2003

I've been updating an older program in fortran90 in an objective way and 
I came across a quite weird behavior of inherited objects: 
As an example:

```
module try_mod

implicit none

type, public :: Inner_t
  integer :: i
  real :: r
end type Inner_t

type, public, extends(Inner_t) :: InnerSpec_t
  integer :: j
end type InnerSpec_t

type, public :: Outer_t
  integer :: nelem
  class( Inner_t ), allocatable, dimension(:) :: elem

contains
  procedure :: init => initOuter

end type Outer_t


contains

 subroutine initOuter(this)
  class(Outer_t), intent(inout) :: this
  integer :: i, suma, k

  this%nelem = 4

  allocate( InnerSpec_t :: this%elem(1:this%nelem) )


  this%elem(1:2)%i = -100
  this%elem(3:4)%i = -200


  print*, '1st: ', this%elem(1:this%nelem)%i
  print*, '2nd: ', this%elem(1)%i, this%elem(2)%i, this%elem(3)%i, this%elem(4)%i

  this%elem(1)%i = 91 
  this%elem(2)%i = 92 
  this%elem(3)%i = 93
  this%elem(4)%i = 94 
  print*,'3rd: ', this%elem(1:4)%i
  print*,'4th: ', this%elem(1)%i, this%elem(2)%i, this%elem(3)%i, this%elem(4)%i



end subroutine initOuter

end module try_mod 

program adgo
  use try_mod

implicit none

  type( Outer_t ) :: outer

  call outer%init()
end program
```

If I compile this program with gfortran (4.8 or 4.9) I get

```
 1st:         -100        -100        -200        -200
 2nd:         -100       32751        -200  1852387182
 3rd:           91        -100        -200          93
 4th:           91          92          93          94
```

altough the 1st and 2nd row (resp. 3rd and 4th) should be the same. It looks like there is some problem with memory allocation for inherited objects, since this problem dissappears if I comment declaration of the variable j (in InnerSpec_t). 
If compiled with intel fortran, everything works fine.

Am I using somehow inappropriate contructs? Is there a way how to make this work even for gfortran?

Comment: At first glance, it does indeed look like a gfortran bug.  Can you file a PR under https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ ?

Comment: @tkoenig : Unfortunatelly I am not sure how to do that... Do I have to make an account there? And btw what does PR mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks very much like a bug in gfortran.  I have submitted [PR 65359](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65359) for this (PR is for "Problem Report").

Comment: I recently looked at this bug report in  PR 65359 and tried this program again with gfortran 5.3 and it still does not work. Could you please explain me why no one was assigned to this bug? Is this example somehow nonstandard (no one uses such constructs) or is it just because no one cares about fortran anymore?